# Laravel Eloquent filter relationship by last pivot record

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

I've got 3 tables: `user`, `role` and pivot `user_role`. There is many-to-many relationship between user and role.

And one more detail, every assignment (role to user) has `timestamp` in `user_role` table, so I can find what role has been added recently for user.

Is there a possibility to write an eloquent query to get all users which **recently** assigned role has e.g id = 5?

I need somehow to get last record from `pivot` ordered by `timestamp` and then use it in `whereHas` statement. But how to get that last record?

### Edit

Thank you for your answers. But I would like to make it all a little bit more complicated. What if we add table `system` and now will be relationship one-to-many between `system` and `user`, so user can belong to one system and system can have multiple users.

And now, how to get e.g. id of `system` which contains users having last role with id = 5 (as at the beginning).

Answer (score 2):

This gives the last user ordered by `timestamp` column from `user_role` table.

```
$user->roles()->withPivot('timestamp')->orderBy('user_role.timestamp','desc')->first();
```

**Update:**

```
$users=User::with(['system','role'=>function($query)
{
   $query->orderBy('pivot_timestamps','desc');
}])->get();
```

then, this gives system id of all the users ordered by timestamps in pivot table.

```
foreach($users as $user)
{
      $user->system->id;
}
```

Make sure you have relations in user and role model `withPivot.` so that you can use `pivot_timestamps`

```
return $this->belongsToMany('users')->withPivot('timestamps');
```

Comment: Is it possible, to get last record from pivot ordered by timestamp within method from Model? So I will be able to do this: System::('users.lastRole, function($q){...}). It works for me but now I have 'users.roles' and it gives me all roles that I can query by closure, but I just need now to have 'users.lastRole'.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to make sure your relationship includes pivot timestamps:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Then you can use the following query in your code to get all users who have recently received a specific role (e.g. id=5).

```
$role = Role::with(['users', function($query) {
    $query->orderBy('pivot_created_at', 'DESC');
}])->find(5);

// all users with (role_id = 5) ordered by (user_role.created_at DESC)
$users = $role->users;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add pivot columns to your relation, like this :

```
/**
 * The roles that belong to the user.
 */
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->withPivot('timestamp');
}
```

Then if you want to check if user has a specific role recently I'd do this

```
public function hasRecentRole($roleId, $howRecently = 'last week')
{
     return $this->roles()->where('id', $roleId)->wherePivot('timestamp', '>', new Carbon\Carbon($howRecently))->count();
}
```

**EDIT:** Try something like this.

```
$systems = System::whereHas('users', function ($query) {
    $query->whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
        $query->where('id', 5)
            ->whereRaw('timestamp = (select max(`timestamp`) from user_roles WHERE user_id = role_user.user_id'));
    });
})->get();
```

If not maybe you ought to work in steps. Like get users with latest role 5 then get system that has at least one of these users.

Comment: Is it possible, to get last record from pivot ordered by timestamp within method from Model? So I will be able to do this: System::('users.lastRole, function($q){...}). It works for me but now I have 'users.roles' and it gives me all roles that I can query by closure, but I just need now to have 'users.lastRole'.